# "Effect of freezing on/of water"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct?

> This video shows the effect of freezing **on** water.
>   This video shows the effect of freezing **of** water.

Comment: @JasperLoy "effect ... on", but "freezing ... of", that should be clear to the discerning reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This video shows the effect of freezing on water

refers to how freezing something has an effect on water.

> This video shows the effect of freezing of water

refers to the effect the freezing of water has on something.

They mean different things but could refer to the same thing; for example, how freezing water makes it expand from four to zero degrees.

Comment: Although it might be slightly contrived, you could also say *salt has an effect **on** freezing **of** water* (I can't even think of a *highly* contrived way to make ***on** freezing **on** water* sound credible!). But OP isn't asking about about different possible meanings - he just asks about which one is "correct" for the most obvious meaning. Although to be honest, I don't particularly agree the semantic distinction you make here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think both sentences are examples of poor style. As far as I know, there's only one "effect of  freezing on water": ice.

> The video shows what happens when water freezes.

is a more reasonable way of saying it.

> The video shows the effect on water of temperatures below freezing (0 C; 32 F).

is also more reasonable but a bit clumsy.

Comment: Close - but I'd say "This video shows that freezing *is* the effect on water of reducing it to 0°C (32°F)."

Comment: @StoneyB: Put a little salt or alcohol into the water and reducing it to 0°C (32°F) doesn't do the trick. [Supercool the water and it won't freeze at those temps either](http://chemistry.about.com/od/waterchemistry/f/freezing-point-of-water.htm). Your sentence is scientifically incorrect because it's imprecise and only theoretically true.

Comment: In the first instance you're not reducing water to that temperature, you're reducing a solution to that temperature. And I'm just telling you what's in the video -- you'll have to argue with the producers about supercooling. :)

Comment: @StoneyB: Now things are getting complicated. :-( Too many facts spoil the English.

Comment: @Bill: Facts affect your English? Faintheart!

Comment: @T: "Faintheart"? Not I. Like all bravehearts, I'm often inclined to linguistic & semantic violence in the name of "Freedom Of Expression" (FOE) [no explanation necessary, I think].

Answer (score 1):

Freezing in common parlance has an effect only on water, so the sentence sounds odd, somewhat like talking about `the effect of cracking on eggs`, or `the effect of rotting on apples`. However it could be saved by using a formulation like:

> ...the effect of freezing temperatures on water.